# Docker NodeJS with MySQL connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

I have 2 container which is mysql and nodejs. However, the connection between my nodejs and mysql doesnt seem to be connected. The error is

```
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
```

My server.js file

```js
//Connection with database
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  port: "8000",
  user: "root",
  password: "root",
  database: "justcall"
});

  con.connect(function(err){
          if(err){
            console.log('Database connection error: ' + err.message);
          }else{
            console.log('Database connection successful');
          }
        });
```

Dockerfile for my nodejs

```js
FROM node:12
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash admin
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN chown -R admin:admin /app
RUN chmod 755 /app
USER admin
CMD npm start
EXPOSE 4443
```

I build the image using

```
docker build -t nodejs:signalingserver2
```

I run the container using

```
docker run -p 4443:4443 nodejs:signalingserver2
```

My mysql docker-compose is

```js
version: '3'
services:

  mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0
        container_name: mysql-server-80
#        command: --default-authentication-plugin=msql_native_password
#       working dir: /application
        volumes:
          - .:/application
        restart: always
        ports:
          - '3306:3306'
        expose:
          - '3306'
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
          - MYSQL_USER=root
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOSTS: mysql

  php:
    container_name: php
    image: php:php_img
    build:
      context: ./
    volumes:
      - /root/app/xampp/justcall:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: always
```

The problem is everytime i run my nodejs server, it has an error which is ECONNREFUSED

Comment: the problem might be unable to reach the endpoint and server might not be running on that port

Comment: is that the problem? I got "Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.18.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message". So i change the ip from localhost to 172.18.0.4 but i got new error which is ETIMEDOUT

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect with php-myadmin, not with MySQL.

Try to change your connection to

```
//Connection with database
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "mysql",
  port: "3306",
  user: "root",
  password: "root",
  database: "mydb"
});
```

Also, add the nodejs container to docker-compose or add legacy linking between nodejs container and MySQL container. when you use `localhost` it refers to the localhost of node container, so you need to use docker-networking to connect with DB container from nodejs container. check [service to service communication](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/).

```
docker run -it --link mysql -p 4443:4443 nodejs:signalingserver2
```

also, uncomment this `command: --default-authentication-plugin=msql_native_password`, mysql 8 does not support plain authutication.

With docker-compose it can be

```
version: '3'
services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=msql_native_password
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
  nodejs:
    image: nodejs:signalingserver2
    ports:
      - '4443:4443'
```

Comment: when i use docker run -it --link mysql -p 4443:4443 nodejs:signalingserver2, i got an error "Unable to find image 'nodejs:signalserver' locally                                                                                                 docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for nodejs, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied."

Comment: however, i can run through docker-compose. I am still new with this and its kind of confusing.